# Create hash using block (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, hash, block

Can I create a Ruby Hash from a block?

Something like this (although this specifically isn't working):

```
foo = Hash.new do |f|
  f[:apple] = "red"
  f[:orange] = "orange"
  f[:grape] = "purple"
end
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you trying this approach because you do this when creating new ActiveRecord objects?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I cannot understand why

```
foo = {
  :apple => "red",
  :orange => "orange",
  :grape => "purple"
}
```

is not working for you?

I wanted to post this as comment but i couldn't find the button, sorry

Comment: you need 50 reputation before you can post comments. You should be able to leave comments now your answer has been upvoted.

Answer (score 18):

In Ruby 1.9 (or with ActiveSupport loaded, e.g. in Rails), you can use `Object#tap`, e.g.:

```
foo = Hash.new.tap do |bar|
  bar[:baz] = 'qux'
end
```

You can pass a block to `Hash.new`, but that serves to define default values:

```
foo = Hash.new { |hsh, key| hsh[key] = 'baz qux' }
foo[:bar]   #=> 'baz qux'
```

For what it's worth, I am assuming that you have a larger purpose in mind with this block stuff. The syntax `{ :foo => 'bar', :baz => 'qux' }` may be all you really need.

Comment: I have a fixture file that is more or less a bunch of ActiveRecord create method calls. Wanted to pretty it up for readability.

Answer (score 5):

Passing a block to `Hash.new` specifies what happens when you ask for a non-existent key.

```
foo = Hash.new do |f|
  f[:apple] = "red"
  f[:orange] = "orange"
  f[:grape] = "purple"
end
foo.inspect # => {}
foo[:nosuchvalue] # => "purple"
foo # => {:apple=>"red", :orange=>"orange", :grape=>"purple"}
```

As looking up a non-existent key will over-write any existing data for `:apple`, `:orange` and `:grape`, you don't want this to happen.

Here's the link to the [Hash.new specification](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002840).

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with

```
foo = {
  apple:  'red',
  orange: 'orange',
  grape:  'purple'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, simple hash syntax may get you what you want.

```
# Standard hash
foo = {
  :apple => "red",
  :orange => "orange",
  :grape => "purple"
}
```

But if you use the "tap" or Hash with a block method, you gain some extra flexibility if you need. What if we don't want to add an item to the apple location due to some condition? We can now do something like the following:

```
# Tap or Block way...
foo = {}.tap do |hsh|
  hsh[:apple] = "red" if have_a_red_apple?
  hsh[:orange] = "orange" if have_an_orange?
  hsh[:grape] = "purple" if we_want_to_make_wine?
}
```